# Is it possible to add mean of each group in tbl_regression

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to add mean of each group in my output of
tbl_regression from gt_summary package. And if it possible the df and satistic value of Anova from car of my model.

I have for example :

```
df <- data.frame ( treatment = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                  treatment_sequence = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                  treatment_response = c(-43.5, 135.0, 8.4, -7.2, 99.0, 159.0, 12.0, -27.0, 3.0, 12.0, -15.0, 91.5, 6.0, -9.0, 177.0, 27.0, 52.8, -54.0, -50.7, 63.0, -9.0, 186.0, -72.0, 15.0)
)

mod <- lm(treatment_response ~ as.factor(treatment) + treatment_sequence, data=df) 

mod %>%
tbl_regression ()
```

And I would like the global p for each cateogrical variable (treatment, treatment_sequence) ,
the mean of each group of treatment and treatment_sequence